# Importing 10000 rows to Solr fetches hundreds of thousands of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, configuration, solr

I'm trying to import five or so tables from MS SQL Server 2005 to Solr 4.3.0 on Ubuntu.  Ultimately I want to import all the rows in each table, but for now I'm using "top (10000)" to limit my import time, until I can get my configuration and queries debugged.

It's mostly working now, but I have the problem that when I check the status with:

```
http://192.168.1.3:8983/solr/dataimport
```

it tells me it's been running for forty-eight minutes, and fetched over 800,000 rows.  Clearly something is wrong in my configuration but I don't have a clue.

```
<str name="status">busy</str>
<str name="importResponse">A command is still running...</str>
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Time Elapsed">0:48:35.0</str>
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">821</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">8165164</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2013-05-21 18:14:15</str>
</lst>
```

My queries all look like:

```
select top (10000) foo, bar from [DBName].dbo.TableName
```

Possibly my problem is that I'm using nested entities rather than un-nested ones.  I've seen examples of both when studying how to configure data-config.xml, and am unclear what the difference is.

This:

```
<entity>
</entity>
<entity>
</entity>
```

Or this:

```
<entity>
<entity>
</entity>
</entity>
```

I'm using the TemplateTransformer to append the primary keys from my tables into a single uniqueKey called id:

```
<field column="id" template="${GetAds.ADS_WPID},${Foo.MI_WPID},${Bar.MERCHANTID},${Baz.R4SE_WPID},${Boo.CR_WPID}" />
```

I've been beating on Solr for over two weeks, so my new boss is impatient for me to have it done.  I'm so close I can taste it, but don't know how to proceed from here.

Thanks for any advice you can give me.

Comment: If you have access to the sql server, run a trace to see the actual sql that solr is sending to the database to execute.

Comment: Thanks brian.  I've gone home for the night, but I'll give your suggestion a try first thing in the morning.

Comment: If I don't nest the entities, but make them vertically adjacent, I get `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id`, I expect because my use of the TemplateTransformer to concatenate my primary keys into a single id fails to resolve the now out-of-scope symbols.

Comment: My boss requested that I solve our business problem in an alternative way that we know will work, without using Solr.  This because I beat at Solr relentlessly for over two weeks and still can't get it to work.  However, this second solution will take the pressure off us by keeping our customers happy, so after that my boss says he will want me to resume work on Solr, but without such incredible urgency.  We're trying to use Solr in the back end of our web app to solve a serious performance problem.